# Serilog and elasticsearch 5.0

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog

I would like to use serilog to write to elasticsearch 5.0

Serilog already have a sink for this purpose at https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch. Unfortunately this sink only works for elasticsearch v 2.x - it doesn't seem to work with elasticsearch.net 5.0.

Does anyone have experience using serilog and elasticsearch 5.0 together?
Can I modify the sink to use 5.0 or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: bindingRedirect of Elasticsearch.net from older versions to 5.0 seems to work just fine. 
So i guess this is not really an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch* now works with 5.0 out-of-the-box.